# Laravel Project link is not accessible on localhost

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel when i download laravel and run the command **php artisan serve** it gives me project link **http://127.0.0.1:8000/**. For the first time i can access the link perfectly as long as i want but when i restart my machine and access my project with the same link it says **This site can’t be reached** I tried many times by installing new projects but same issue. Anyone please help

Comment: no i am not running any proxy and yes i tried same results there as well

Answer (score 3):

You have to run this command "php artisan serve" every time when you wanna start developing.

Comment: really? is it necessary?

Comment: Unfortunately, Yes. 
You can avoid it if you install some WEB server, such as Apache, Nginx, and so on.

Comment: Yes every time you have to run this command in order to get your application working